# Unable to access phone after update to iOS 12.1.4

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, software-update

I recently updated my iPhone 5S to iOS 12.1.4 and I can't access it anymore.  The phone says "Press Home to upgrade". My phone's home button is broken so I can't press the Home button. I have assistive touch, but the screen is not responsive to my touch.

I have also tried:

- Trying to restart the phone. When I press the sleep/wake button for a long time, the Apple logo flickers before the phone shuts down. When I long press again, the Apple logo displays, then the white words "iPhone is disabled" and the smaller "please wait 1 minute" is displayed. Eventually, the same screen appears.
- Trying to revert to a backup. After I tried 2 different cables which have been working previously, and making sure the USB input was working, the phone would not be detected by the computer itself.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You said you have assistive touch enabled, but the screen doesn't respond.  Does the screen not respond to anything at all or just within assistive touch?

Comment: I don't know. I think it's assistive touch itself since the screen was working earlier.

Comment: So, the screen isn't working at all right now.

Answer (score 1):

**Connect your iPhone to iTunes**

> If iPhone is locked, iTunes will not recognize that it's connected.

Therefore, you have to put your iPhone to **DFU mode**. Usually, a key combination is used to do that (requires home button).

Other way is to use third party software, which allows you to enter DFU mode with one click.

- **[Recboot](https://download.cnet.com/RecBoot/3000-18553_4-77428313.html)**
- [Tiny Umbrella](https://blog.firmwareumbrella.com)
- [Redsn0w](http://www.iphonehacks.com/download-redsn0w)

> I have not checked, whether second and third option works with your iOS and iPhone, but there are a few others worth trying.

When your iPhone enters DFU mode, you will be able to **manually reinstall iOS using iTunes or recover from backup**.

Answer (score 0):

I think broken home button is the source of the problem. 
I think below can be a solution.

1. Get an external home button like [this](https://9to5mac.com/2018/01/11/ces-2018-apple-accessory-funhouse/). But I do not know this product also works for your iPhone 5S. [There are similar cases like yours](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/480042/Press+home+button+to+upgrade+(broken+home+button)). Some people succeeded but others did not.
2. Boot with [DFU mode](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/DFU_Mode) and revert to backup via iTunes.